# Extension reads wrong data + gt> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

this is my first question here so I will try to provide as much information as needed. First of I have two problems in my code, one is that my extension reads the wrong data.

Instead of the data provided by the jQuery it reads the jQuery code itself, the output should be "1 000 kr" but instead it shows `"$("#v4").text();"`. Which is just silly. The code in my background.js is,

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.text == "getStuff")
    sendResponse({type: ' $("#v4").text(); '});
});
```

And the code in my popup.js is,

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({text:"getStuff"},function(response){
  if(response.type != 0)
  $(".cash").append(response.type);
});
```

---

My second problem is that my greather then `>` is not working as it should be working. When I try the code in my browser console I get the correct output as true/false. But in my code it doesn't work as it should be working,

I.E if the output is true it should fire a `click();` event but it never does it. I even tried parseFloat(), parseInt() and text(). I tried many different methods but none of them worked, they worked in the console but not in the code. My other codes work fine but this one is silly.

```
$('.deposit').on('click', function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    if($("#v4").html().replace(" ", "").replace("kr", "") > 500){ 
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].Id, {code: 'document.getElementById("i4").click();'}); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two problems are pretty easy to solve:

1. In the first snippet **you're actually sending a string** (that is `'$("#v4").text();'`) **instead of the text value** of the element, and, obviously, you will receive a string as response. So to fix this you can simply **remove the quotes and the semicolon** (which isn't allowed inside an object), here is the correct code:

   ```
   chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
       if(message.text == "getStuff") sendResponse({type: $("#v4").text()});
   });
   ```
2. Your second problem is just a silly typo: **you're writing `tabs[0].Id` instead of `tabs[0].id`**. The `.id` property of the `tab` object is lower case. Your code should be:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: 'document.getElementById("i4").click();'});
   ```

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

Comment: This didn't show the value of `#v4`, also a friend of mine told me that background.js doesn't have access to the page html/data since it is a own process.